# Javascript FaceBook API returning Posts of type status

Tags: jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a jquery plugin that supposed to fetch the posts from Facebook Wall page but i am only retrieving the status posts and not all the posts from the wall. Where am i going wrong?

This is the URL i am using:

https://graph.facebook.com/100002102406059/feed?limit=5&access_token=123165947807355|fg-kqzZz3nBr7jvCQpAIUT3CTQY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your library is using Facebook Graph API, probably it's calling the following URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/posts
```

You can change the "posts" to to "feed" at the end like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed
```

You can see the an example preview here:
[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552%2Ffeed](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552/feed)